# AWS Step Functions: проблема с передачей функций в степ "Type": "Map"

Tags: amazon-web-services

Ребята, можете помочь разобраться с тем, как правильно передать параметры в степ "Type": "Map". Мне нужно параллельно запустить несколько задач, которые перекладут данные из одной таблицы в другую. Нужно итеративно для каждого запуска передать свои сорс и таргет таблицы. Пробую для начала передать словарь (sqlserver_tables_list) с этими значениями в подготовительном этапе (Prepare input data), а потом итеративно вызывать их в этапе "Maps Copy to SQL Server". Но что-то не получается. Пишет ошибку: An error occurred while executing the state 'Maps Copy to SQL Server' (entered at the event id #6). The JSONPath '$$.Map.Item.AthenaTableName' specified for the field 'AthenaTableName.$' could not be found in the input

```
{
  "Comment": "Start of data migration",
  "StartAt": "Prepare input data",
  "States": {
    "Prepare input data": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "Run DDL for RedShift",
      "Parameters": {
        "GeneralParameters.$": "$$.Execution.Input.GeneralParameters",
        "DownloadingParameters.$": "$$.Execution.Input.DownloadingParameters",
        "jobs.$": "$$.Execution.Input.DownloadingParameters.GlueRedShiftJobs",
        "common": {
          "extra_jars.$": "",
          "extra_py_files.$": "",
          "s3_output_kms_key.$": ""
        },
        "regular_input": {
          "GeneralParameters.$": "$.GeneralParameters",
          "DownloadingParameters.$": "$.DownloadingParameters",
          "LandingZoneFolders.$": "$.LandingZoneFolders",
          "DebugOptions.$": "$.DebugOptions"
        },
        "redshift_options": {
          "database_name.$": "",
          "secret_name.$": "",
          "region_name.$": ""
        },
        "datalake_options": {
          "iceberg_catalog.$": "",
          "database_name.$": "",
          "athena_output.$": "",
          "kms_key.$": "",
          "sns_topic_arn.$": ""
        },
        "sqlserver_tables_list": {
          "tables": [
            {
              "AthenaTableName": "1",
              "MSSQLTableName": "1"
            },
            {
              "AthenaTableName": "2",
              "MSSQLTableName": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },

"Maps Copy to SQL Server": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.sqlserver_tables_list.tables",
      "MaxConcurrency": 5,
      "Parameters": {
        "common.$": "$.common",
        "datalake_options.$": "$.datalake_options"
      },
      "Next": "Success",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Copy to SQL Server",
        "States": {
          "Copy to SQL Server": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "",
            "Parameters": {
              "StateMachineArn": "",
              "Input": {
                "job.$": "",
                "common.$": "$.common",
                "input_params": {
                  "datalake_options.$": "$.datalake_options",
                  "extra_options": {
                    "source_table.$": "$$.Map.Item.AthenaTableName",
                    "target_table.$": "$$.Map.Item.MSSQLTableName",
                    "mssql_server_host": "",
                    "mssql_server_port": "",
                    "mssql_server_username": "",
                    "mssql_server_password": "",
                    "athena_output.$": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Next": "Success (2)",
            "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "Pass (1)",
                "ResultPath": "$.exception_info"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Pass (1)": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
          },
          "Success (2)": {
            "Type": "Succeed"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```